# How can I get whole HTML code using Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get whole HTML code to get some data from web in Unity. I checked the Unity documents, and I followed the example which is written in Unity doc. But all I can get is These Logs.

```
<!DOCTPYE HTML>
<html>
```

Is there any way to get a whole HTML Code in Unity?
This is my code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(GetText());
    }

    IEnumerator GetText() {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://gunwoo7.github.io/My_blog/Test.html");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You content is already there!

In the log [Console Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html) Unity by default only displays the **first two lines** of each message.

But if you click on it you will see the complete message in the lower part of the console (`Test` just executes your exact code):

[image]

---

You can also adjust this and display more then the two lines (up to 10) via

[image]

so now you can see all (up to 10) lines at once

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not good at Unity that much, so I didn't realize that The console log only showed 2 Lines. Thanks to tell me about that